# 'A' record for a host name on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Could anyone tell me what is a 'A' record and how to set it up for a host name on Amazon EC2?
I need to forward a 'A' record to amazon so that they could take off my email limitation.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

An A Record is used to point a logical domain name, such as "google.com", to the IP address of Google's hosting server, "74.125.224.147".

You need to assign Elastic IP to an EC2 instance , so that you can use this IP in DNS records for this instance .

Comment: Then go to your DNS provider (godaddy/AWS Route 53...) and add A record as this EIP against your domain name .

Comment: Can my public DNS ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com serve as a domain name or should I register one with godaddy? You also call this as 'cname', right? This is where my understanding is. Anyhow, I went ahead and created a A record on Amazon Route 53 and submitted this form(  https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) to remove the email limitation.The response from AWS is that I have multiple PTR records mapped to a single EIP. Now this is another loop hole I need figure out.

Comment: you can map ur Public DNS as a CNAME with Godaddy ,thats right .

Comment: Manjunath - +1 for directing me to a DNS provider.